# Getting error while testing transfer function using chai

Tags: solidity, truffle, testing, chai

I have a function that transfers the amount from owner to user. I'm getting success in the event emitted message and my test is failing every time.

Here is my code.

```
function investInMPay(uint256 _amount) public validateInvestor(_amount) {
        Investors[msg.sender] = investor(block.timestamp, _amount);
        transferTokenToInvestor(msg.sender, _amount);
    }

function transferTokenToInvestor(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
       require(balanceOf[owner] >= _value);
        _transfer(owner, _to, _value);
        return true; 
    }

function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) internal {
        require(_to != address(0));
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value, balanceOf[_to]);
    }
```

Here is a test that I have written.

```
it('test token transfer', async () => {
                invest = await Invest.new();
                await invest.investInMPay(ether(1), { from: user })
                let result = await token.balanceOf(user)
                assert.equal(result.toString(),tokens(1).toString());
            })
```

While running the test I'm getting following error.

```
Events emitted during test:
---------------------------

    Token.Transfer(
      from: <indexed> 0xf3a429e4FAFf561f5AD75A3F944Bc14432b225ee (type: address),
      to: <indexed> 0x273638fa06e2A6870566D1fbe5F3D37402A95655 (type: address),
      _value: 1000000000000000000 (type: uint256),
      balance: 1000000000000000000 (type: uint256)
    )
<----ERROR---->
    success
          test token transfer:
    
          AssertionError: expected '0' to equal '1000000000000000000'
          + expected - actual
    
          -0
          +1000000000000000000
```

Comment: what is tokens?

Comment: tokens is my function which transfers ether to wei. @JavierMarchetti

Comment: This line seems a bit off to me: { let result = await token.balanceOf(user) }
What is the [token.] in this case (Seems like you are sending ETH, but getting balance of some ERC20 token, or something like that)

Comment: Actually, I have a function that transfers ERC20 tokens in exchange for ETH. So transferTokenToInvestor functions transfer the ERC20 token. And I want to check that transfer balance to the user balance. @Sky

Comment: What does your `_transfer` function look like? Can you update your question with the `_transfer` function?

Comment: Question updated @PatrickCollins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       await invest.investInMPay(ether(1), { from: user })
       let result = await token.balanceOf(user)
```

I think this is `token.balanceOf` not returning updated state. In "invest" contract you already have `balanceOf` mapping so if you get the result directly from the mapping it should work. if you define the `balanceOf` inside `invest` contact

```
function balanceOf(address _owner) public view override returns (uint256 balance){
        // since name of the func is balanceOf, I named the mapping as tokenBalances
        return tokenBalances[_owner];
    }
```

so get the result:

```
   let result = await invest.balanceOf(user)
```

It is not clear what `token` is in your testing function. probably `token` is another contract you keep the state, but that state is not getting updated and when you write `invest.balanceOf(user)` you are getting 0 as the default value. In solidity mapping, if the key does not exist, since you probably defined mapping `mapping(address=>uint) balanceOf`, you are getting a default value of 0 for `uint`

Comment: You guessed it, right man. It works. Thank you.